# $f$ is an analytic function in the disk $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,|z|\leq 2\}$ such that $\iint_D=|f(z)|^2\,dx\,dy\leq 3\pi$. Maximize $|f''(0)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, greens-theorem

> Determine the largest possible value of $|f''(0)|$ when $f$ is an analytic function in the disk $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,|z|<2\}$ with the property that $\iint_{D}|f(z)|^2\,dx\,dy\leq 3\pi$.

I don't really know what to do with the assumption that $\iint_D|f(z)|^2\,dx\,dy\leq 3\pi$. I believe you could use Stokes' theorem to rewrite this as a line integral on $\partial D$, but I'm really rusty with my usage, so I'm kind of stuck.

If I could get a bound on $\int_{\partial D}|f(z)|^2\,dz$, I could probably use harnack's inequality for subharmonic functions to get a bound on $|f|$ then Cauchy's inequality, however I'm not very sure about my usage of green's theorem (if that's even the right way to go) any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\langle f,f \rangle=\iint_Df(z)\times\overline{f(z)}dxdy=\iint_D |f(z)|^2dxdy \leqslant 3\pi$$

Power series of $f(z)$ about $z=0$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$$
then you can easily prove (using polar coordinates, **edit:** or more easily by defining a base using $z^n$ then using the generalized form of Parseval's Identity) that $$\langle f,f \rangle=\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|^2\times 2^{2n+2}}{n+1} \leqslant 3\pi$$
$$\pi \frac{|a_2|^2\times 2^{2*2+2}}{2+1} \leqslant \pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|^2\times 2^{2n+2}}{n+1} \leqslant 3\pi$$
$$|f''(0)/2!|^2\times\frac{64}{3} \leqslant3$$
$$|f''(0)| \leqslant\frac{3}{4}$$

*CAVEAT* : there might be more than a few mistakes, it's been some time since I've last done something like this.

Comment: $2^6=64$ so the estimate should be $3/4.$

Comment: @zhw. thank you, fixed it.

Comment: Is that bound sharp?

Comment: @anomaly I think so, $|f^{(n)}(0)|^2$ could be null for all possible values of $n$ except $n=2$, conversely $|f''(0)|^2$ could equal $0$ so the inequality still holds.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $f$ as a power series, use polar coordinates on $\int_D |f|^2,$ and use the orthogonality of the exponentials.